# rpmbuild specfile - how to set env %{python_sitearch}

Tags: python, rpmbuild

Is it possible to configure the .spec file to include the `%{python_sitearch}/foo_c_dir` into my system's env when .rpm installation time?

In rpmbuild spec file, there exist `%files` section which includes `%{python_sitearch}/dir/` path. And the dir includes some c library files.

```
%files devel
%defattr(-, root, root,-)
%{_libdir}/foo_c.so
%{_libdir}/pkgconfig/foo_c.pc
%{_includedir}/foo_c_dir
%{python_sitearch}/foo_c_dir
```

After installing this -devel-.rpm package, necessary files and directories are copied into my Linux.

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/foo_c_dir/foo_cmodule.so
```

But the `%{python_sitearch}/foo_c_dir/` path is not configured to the system's env. So to use this path I have to include this path manually in my python script, like

```
import os, sys, site
sys.path.append(os.path.join(site.getsitepackages()[0], 'foo_c_dir/'))
```

I think this is inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify environmental variables when a user is logged in, the usual approach is to drop a file in `/etc/profile.d/`. You should probably have one for each major shell type (`sh` vs. `csh`).